# Bug: unable to cast close votes

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I'm unable to cast close votes, even though I have enough reputation that I'm supposed to be able to.

For instance, when I go to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/where-can-find-sample-coding-for-use-of-bouncy-castlejava) and click on "close (1)" while logged in, I get a rectangular popup with a yellow background, saying "Unable to load popup - please try again (click on this box to dismiss)".

Any idea why this happens, or how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache, or force reloading the page with ctrl+f5?

Comment: Yes, I have tried clearing my browser cache, force-reloading the page, restarting my browser, etc.  I can reliably reproduce it.  Clicking on "close" never works for me; I consistently get the symptoms mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this. Try clearing your browser cache, etc.

Comment: I've tried all that, and still experience these symptoms.  Any more ideas on how to debug the problem?

Comment: @d.w. can you try a different web browser? We often see plugins interfere, too.

Answer (score 1):

This now has started working for me, so this thread can be closed/disregarded.

Comment: Yay!  Another janitor! :)